# Python: curve_fit for least squares minimization

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

Lets say I have a model `f` which is parametrized by `t`. I want the optimal value for `t` such that `∑ₓ (f(x, t) - y(x))²` is minimized. This is what least squares optimization is for.

In the following example

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = arange(100)

t_true = 30
y = 1. / (1 + exp(-(x - t_true) / 5.))

f = lambda x, t: [0. if xi < t else 1. for xi in x]
t_opt, t_cor = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=(20.))

plot(x, y)
plot(x, f(x, t_opt))

print(t_cor)
```

why do I get `t_opt=20` and not something close to `t_opt=30`?

Also, why is `t_cor=inf`? The result I get is:

[image]

where blue is the data and green is the fitted model, but I expect something that looks like this:

[image]

I do expect this because the sum of squared residuals from the second image is sure smaller than it is for the first image and there obviously is no local minimum where the optimization could possibly stuck. So why isn't that working?

Comment: Do you want to find the best value of x (say xopt) that gives the minimized error for distance(y(x) - xopt)?

Comment: @SaulloCastro No, my model is the function `f` which is parametrized by `t`. I want the optimal value for `t` such that `∑ₓ (f(x, t) - y(x))²` is minimized

Answer (score 1):

`curve_fit` [is a wrapper](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) around `least_sq` that uses the following error function:

```
 def error(params, x, y):
    return np.sum((func(x, params) - y)**2)
```

In your question `curve_fit` did not work because the equation you are trying to fit is very different from the equation you used to generate `y`.

The recommended function to fit in this case would be (with `t` as unknown):

```
def f(x, t):
    return 1. / (1 + exp(-(x - t) / 5.))
```

With this recommended fitting function, `curve_fit` will work, or you can use `scipy.optimize.leastsq` directly like:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp
from scipy.optimize import leastsq, curve_fit

x = np.arange(100)

t_true = 30

def f(x, t):
    return 1. / (1 + exp(-(x - t) / 5.))

y = f(x, t_true)

def error(t, x, y):
    return np.sum((f(x, t) - y)**2)

t_opt, t_cor = leastsq(error, args=(x, y), x0=1.)
print('least_sq', t_opt, t_cor)

t_opt2, t_cor2 = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=(0,))
print('curve_fit', t_opt2, t_cor2)
```

Which will give you:

```
least_sq [ 30.00000007] 2
curve_fit [ 30.] [[ 0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was why `curve_fit` isn't working :) The point is, I need the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm (which `curve_fit` can use) for benchmarking, but the documentation of `leastsq` doesn't say anything regarding which algorithm it uses.

Comment: @theV0ID if you use the same function `f(x, t)` above in `curve_fit`  it should work as well, since `curve_fit`  is just a wrapper around `leastsq`

Comment: @theV0ID it seems the problem is with the function you are passing to `curve_fit`

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by *"the equation you are trying to fit is very different from the equation you used to generate `y`"*? Is it that `curve_fit` fails at sampling a reliable gradient? But, why does `leastsq` work then? To put it in a different way: What does `leastsq` do what `curve_fit` does not?

Comment: @I meat that the equation you used to generate the data is too different from the fitting equation. In this case, even if `curve_fit` could find the best coefficients for your fitting  equation, it wouldn't be enough. This is not a problem with `curve_fit` I updated the example showing how `curve_fit` gives the same result as `leastsq`